Deducing Equivalent Norms on Sobolev Spaces from Boundary Value Problems
In Salsa's Partial Differential Equations in Action, 3ed page 540 the following is mentioned:

Let $\Omega$ be a $C^2-$ domain and $f \in L^2(\Omega)$. 
The Lax-Milgram Theorem and Theorem 8.28 (Elliptic regularity theorem) imply that the
solution of the Dirichlet problem
$$ \begin{cases}-\Delta u=f & \text { in } \Omega \\ u=0 & \text { on
 } \partial \Omega \end{cases} $$
belongs to $H^2(\Omega) \cap H_0^1(\Omega)$ and that
$$ \|u\|_{H^2(\Omega)} \leq C\|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}=C\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} $$

Then it right after:

Since clearly we have $\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq\|u\|_{H^2(\Omega)}$, we draw the following important conclusion:
Corollary 8.30. If $u \in H^2(\Omega) \cap H_0^1(\Omega)$, then
$$ \|\Delta u\|_0 \leq\|u\|_{H^2(\Omega)} \leq C_b\|\Delta u\|_0 $$
In other words, $\|\Delta u\|_0$ and $\|u\|_{H^2(\Omega)}$ are
equivalent norms in $H^2(\Omega) \cap H_0^1(\Omega)$.

I understand both passages. However, my question is why the corollary states that the inequality is true for arbitrary $u \in H^2 \cap H^1_0$ while the right-hand side of the inequality is only true for solutions of the problem?

What does the $0$ subscript on the norms in the last inequality denote?

@whpowell96 that means that the functions vanish at the boundary. $H^1_0$ is defined to be the functions in $H^1$ that vanish at the boundary.

I know what it means for a space, but what type of norm is it? Is it an $L^2$ norm?

@whpowell96 Sorry, I thought you were talking about the space. Yes, it is the $L^2$ norm.

Let $u\in H^2(\Omega) \cap H^1_0(\Omega)$ be arbitrary, $f=-\Delta u$, and $v\in H^2(\Omega) \cap H^1_0(\Omega)$ be the unique solution to \begin{equation}
\left \{ \begin{split}
-\Delta v &= f, \qquad \text{in } \Omega \\
v&=0, \qquad \text{on } \partial \Omega.
\end{split} \right . \tag{$\ast$}\end{equation} By the first result, $$ \| v\|_{H^2(\Omega)}\leq C\| f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}=C\| \Delta u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}. $$ But $u$ also satisfies $(\ast)$, so by uniqueness, $v=u$. Hence, $$ \| u\|_{H^2(\Omega)}\leq C\| \Delta u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} $$ for arbitrary $u\in H^2(\Omega) \cap H^1_0(\Omega)$.

Awesome! It is interesting how you use a "uniqueness" concept to justify a "arbitrariness" concept. What if the solution of the problem is not unique for some reason... would this break down?
